# How to remove a comment based on it's field value?

Tags: nodes, comments

I have a multilingual site, Comments in this site include a language field (`field_language`), so users who send comment to nodes must specify in what language they are sending the comment. On loading a node I want to display only the comments which their `field_language` is equal to the current website language. I tried this code based on the following result

[image]

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    global $language;
    foreach ($variables['content']['comments']['comments'] as $comment)
        if($comment['field_language']['#items'][0]['value'] != $language->language)
            unset($comment);
}
```

The `$comment['field_language']['#items'][0]['value']` prints the comment `field_language` so I'm sure this is a correct syntax and the condition holds for a few comments but `unset($comment);` doesn't unset the comment.

I tried the following code

```
unset($variables['content']['comments']['comments'][71]);
```

and it successfully worked and removed the comment. The ID inside the `[]` is stored in the `$comment['#entity_view_mode']['id']`, I can easily use this ID to remove the comment but I think there must a more straightforward solution.

Is there any other solution like using `hook_comment_load` or anything else?

Comment: Interesting question and I will use this in the future. +1 :)

Comment: @herci Andrew answer completes my solution but I'm still waiting for other solutions

Answer (score 2):

This code should work for you

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  global $language;
  foreach ($variables['content']['comments']['comments'] as $key => $comment) {
    if ($comment['field_language']['#items'][0]['value'] != $language->language) {
      unset($variables['content']['comments']['comments'][$key]);
    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: I don't like the [0] and ['value']. What if that changes? entity_metadata_wrappers could clean this up. but then again, this adds a dependency to entity. But when is this a problem?

Comment: @Pinoniq I always use entity module. But here is a problem, I need to remove some comments based on the site language. My approach only removes the comments from the current page and it won't alter the Database, in fact it changes the way to display content. But when you use `entity_metadata_wrappers` you must use `save()` function which causes to completely remove that comment from the database. so it won't work in here. Besides that it only remains `[0]` because every comment has exactly one language field